# My pc is stuck in a serious boot loop

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

So I recently installed Ubuntu and wanted to uninstalled it, so I followed a guide that told me to just delete the Ubuntu partition (nothing else) and so I did but a few days later I wanted to reinstall it so I got my usb flash drive plugged it in and wanted to boot on it but selected the wrong drive that was called « ubuntu » and then the grub (with only the command prompt) showed up so I manually booted on Windows, followed a guide to uninstall the grub, rebooted and then a blank page with written « reset system » shows up and then it shuts down then does it again and again.

Btw it’s a Lenovo ideapad gaming 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can get to your bios screen, then set your boot device order to list the USB drive that has the installation media for Ubuntu.  Then reboot with a jump drive that contains the installation media for Ubuntu in the USB drive that you specified in the BIOS.  That will let you boot Ubuntu in either Try mode or full install.  Either of those options should give you access to manage your storage and partitions.

Comment: No, I can’t even reach the bios I can’t directly boot to bios with a Lenovo notebook and even if I could, the pc doesn’t even seem to load the kernel

Comment: Ok imma contact lenovo

Comment: Here is a link to how to access the bios on an Lenovo ideapad device. 
 I agree with @Nmath - it is really rare to brick the motherboard. 
 https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/330-15igm/81d1/solutions/ht500216-recommended-way-to-enter-bios-ideapad

Comment: Oh thanks a lot actually the bios loads so fast that I can’t know if it loaded. I managed to change the boot order

Comment: Glad my answer was able to help.